# Recommendation on JavaFX grid

Tags: java, javafx, grid

I am currently developing a game on Java and I am required to have GUI elements for it (using JavaFX). The game will be similar to Snakes And Ladders. There must a zig zag board.During the game play, after a dice roll, a player will have to move.  I am not sure what would be the best solution when it comes to having a grid (board) on the game. What I need is to have separate indexes on every squares, so I could tell game that this is just a regular square, or the square that you stepped on has a specific function to do (for example go back few steps). Would it be the best solution to implement this game using GridPane to draw the board? Thank you.

Comment: Please add an image to describe how "zig zag board" should look like

Comment: this is way too broad plus asking for "best" approaches is asking for being buried under tons of answers, all with different approaches :) Start with what you think will work, then refine - when stuck, come back with  a specific answer about the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best thing for you would be to go with `GridPane` of a size for example 16x16 with setting your own `ColumnConstraints` and `RowConstraints` for it which will resemble a board on which snake can move.

As for game logic, you can implement that each index of a board( `GridPane` ) will have a child of a special object( call it `Field` ) which will hold `Rectangle`, shape with width and height of that board index, and some specific logic regarding feature for that field.

Bare in mind that gridpane and buttons resembling logic of a game, draw dice and similar, should be children of `AnchorPane`.

Link:
[ColumnConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html), [RowConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html)